# Cannot connect to Mysql using java jdbc Driver

Tags: java, mysql, linux, hibernate, tomcat

I am building an application in Tomcat 7, using Spring Data and hibernate. I have it working on my mac, but when I ported the application over to my linux server, and changed the configuration to match that MySQL login, I get a Connection Exception on Tomcat startup.

A couple differences between my development environment (where it works) and my production environment(where it doesn't work):
-Development is mac, production is linux
-Development MySQL version: Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.16, for osx10.9 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper,  Production MySQL version: Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.37, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.2

hibernate.properties looks like this:

```
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
hibernate.connection.driver_class=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/<dbname>
hibernate.connection.username=root
hibernate.connection.password=<root password>
```

One weird thing is that on my linux box, mysql doesn't show up when typing the netstat command, but I can log in from the command line no problem. When in mysql, I typed "show variables;" and port came back as 0. Tomcat still couldn't connect when I put this port into the hibernate properties though.

Comment: when I ps aux | grep mysql i get the following:

Comment: mysql    28881  0.0  1.1 615828 43844 ?        Sl   Jun02   3:34 /usr/sbin/mysqld --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that MySQL was not running correctly. Port number was 0 and --skip-networking was on. I restarted MySQL and it started correctly the next time. After this I could succcesfully connect.

Answer (score 0):

Can you create the database `<dbname>` from the mysql command line?
Are you sure that mysqld is running correctly? What do you mean by the port came back as 0?

How do you deploy your application with tomcat? Do you use the tomcat7 debian package or another one? What does the message exception say exactly?

Comment: I can create the database from the mysql command line, and I already have created it. I package my spring app using maven, name the war ROOT.war, and put it in $TOMCAT_HOME/webapps, then run $TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/bin/startup.sh.

Comment: The port coming back as 0 is exactly what I said. From the mysql command line, I type "show variables;" and many variables come back. The port variable shows as 0.